# Chrbuntu Graphics Acceleration on Acer C7 Chromebook running 13.10

Tags: 13.10, chromebook

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 on my Acer C7 Chromebook. The System is not finding the drivers for the graphics card and is reporting graphics as being

Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe(LLVM 3.3 128 bits)

The system runs very slowly.

How can I enable the graphics drivers for the X Server again?

I have tried using the latest intel open source driver installer from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads.

The program installs correctly on the chromebook but stops running, reporting that it has not found the intel915 chipset.

---

OK.. seems that the issue is related to the kernel in chrubuntu (which is 3.4) whilst the newer versions of Ubuntu have moved on. GLX requires version 3.6 or greater and glxinfo will crash if invoked with kernel 3.4

The question becomes... how does one install a newer kernel on an acer chrome hardware.

Comment: Upgraded to 14.04 LTS with the same problem.